# Should JOIN operations be replaced by multi-table SELECTs?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Given these two tables:

```
A.a   B.b
-     -
1     3
2     4
3     5
4     6
```

If I want **a cross matching** I can do both

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.a = B.b; # and
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON (A.a = B.b)
```

Or if I want a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** or **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM A,B WHERE A.a = B.b(+); # and
SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (A.a = B.b)
```

But are there any engine/performance differences between query statements?

Comment: No, they produce the exact same query plan.

Comment: They ***should*** generate the same plan.  But on *some* RDBMS the old notation *sometimes* fails; giving either a poor query plan or possibly even an incorrect query plan *(and so incorrect results)* - Although this is rare, I have encountered.  The ANSI-92 syntax is not prone to this problem, and is a lot more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They most likely generate the same plan on modern RDBMS. The `JOIN` syntax is the ANSI SQL syntax since 1992.

Answer (score 0):

*In theory*, the multi-select would first select everything from both tables, store all that data in memory, and then compare each to everyone. But *in practice*, no database would do that. Any modern database would optimize this query so that both the multi-select and the JOIN version are processed identically.